# Photo Gallery kept having "blank image" generated?

Tags: android, image, camera, gallery, photo

There are always "empty images" being generated and stored in the gallery, even though I decided not to take an image and exit the camera screen by pressing on back button? Is there a way to eliminate this continuous "blank image" problem in the `MainActivity.java` without editing in the `CameraPhoto` class in my library? Thanks

MainActivity.java

```
        CameraPicture cameraPhoto = new CameraPicture(getApplicationContext());
                Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                try {
                                    startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);

                                    cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                                }

                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                    String photoPath = cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
                    selectedPhoto = photoPath;
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    try {
                        bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                        ivImage.setImageBitmap(getRotatedBitmap(bitmap,90));


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong while loading the photo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
}
```

EDIT: Created another java class called CameraPicture to host the updated recommended codes instead of calling from the library CameraPhoto .jar file to prevent conflict.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CameraPicture {
    private String photoPath;
    private Context context;

    public String getPhotoPath() {
        return this.photoPath;
    }

    public CameraPicture(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Intent takePhotoIntent() throws IOException {
        Intent in = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        if(in.resolveActivity(this.context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = this.createImageFileName();
            if(photoFile != null) {
                in.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }
        }

        return in;
    }

    private File createImageFileName() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = new File ( storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");
        this.photoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    public void addToGallery() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(this.photoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are causing them your self. `createImageFile()`. You dont need to create that file already. The only thing you need to supply is a path. An uri for that path. `createImageFileName()` will do.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying I used this class from https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil library found online into this project. So I've never expect such problem when using it. Is there anyway around this because i can't edit the stated code .jar where the class is being reference from? And I don't really understand the solution you stated above could you be more precise?

Comment: Do not create the file. `File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);`. You are creating a file with that statement. You only need a name. a path an uri. So do not create the file. Better `File image = new File ( storageDir + "/" + imageFileName +  ".jpg");` And rename the function as i suggested earlier.

Comment: Hi tried what you recommended by creating another class to run the updated codes but blank image still continue to be created in the gallery when i chose not to take a picture and exit the camera view? This is the original project link here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2rvGRbu0A83LU1pQjRicnNFS0U/view

Comment: Sorry i will not follow that link. I only want to see your relevant code.

Comment: Hi updated my post, not sure it helps?

Comment: When are you calling `addToGallery()` ? Please show `onActivityResult()`. On how many devices did you try this?

Comment: Updated the post as stated above. Only once I called addToGallery() as stated in the code above. 2 devices

Comment: `cameraPhoto.addToGallery();` OMG. You are calling that in the on click listener. Very wrong place. You should do that in `onActivityResult`()` only. Only after the picture is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
```

OMG. You are calling that in the on click listener. Very wrong place. You should do that in `onActivityResult()` only.

Only after the picture is taken.

Having said that i find the function name wrong. You are adding nothing to the Gallery as there is no Gallery. There is only a Gallery app. And there are often more Gallery apps. You are adding your file to the MediaStore. The Gallery and Fotos apps query the MediaStore for images.

Comment: Thank You so much!!! I knew somewhere went wrong but did not realize a small mistake could create it..